# Dojo Reload Grid Data Using a JsonRestStore

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid, store

How do I reload the data of a grid using a `JsonRestStore`? With a normal store I could call close() and then set the url property again, but a `JsonRestStore` does not have an url, only a target. I also tried to set the store of the grid again using `setStore`, but this killed the grid completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the setQuery method of the grid.

```
gridObject.setQuery({id:value});
```

Also, make sure that your jsonRestStore has the property cachingFetch set to FALSE. Otherwise it will just fetch stuff from local memory instead of server. (This behaviour may be good or bad depending on your needs)